# How to properly label power wires

Tags: power, wiring

Basic and stupid question, however it bugs people and creates misunderstanding.

I frequently see the following labeling of 3 wires in the cable

- wire 1: "+24 V"
- wire 2: "-24 V"
- wire 3: "ground" or ground electrical symbol (without circle around it).

When I ask people what is the supply voltage, they say: 24V. When I tell them that according to their labeling it must be 48V with central ground. None still have shown me wire 3 being marked "PE" (then it will be clear that it is not a signal ground, and things are not that they appear to be).

Thus what is the correct way to label 3-wire cable so that everyone understands immediately that power voltage is 24VDC?

I think it must be GND, +24V and PE. Is it correct or there're any other ways? What if power supply must be isolated? If power is AC?

Comment: "24 V+" and "24 V-" spring to mind. And, if there are multiple isolated 24 volt supplies "24(A) V+" and "24(B) V+" etc. but that is open to modification.

Answer (score 1):

For industrial applications:

- PE for protective earth. Green / yellow for wiring.
- 0V for 24 V supply common is generally good because its meaning is clear. White with blue stripe is normal in Europe.
- +24V is usually split by fuses, circuit breakers or electronic fault protection units so additional wire numbering is required. +24-1, +24-2, etc., would make it very clear. Blue wiring is common in Europe.

If the power must be isolated I would be inclined then the argument could be made for 24V+ and 24V- (with signs *after* the voltage)
. This should still be adequately clear and does not imply a ±24 V power system.